# how can we change zindex of a silverlight control programmatically?

Tags: silverlight, stackpanel, z-index

I have some controls added in a stackpanel programmatically. What i want to do is that i want one of the controls in this stackpanel to be placed over another control. Specifically, I want to place button over an image in this stack panel. I couldn't find zindex property in c# codebehind. Although it seems very simple problem but i am unable to find any clue to solve this problem. Anyone please......??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try placing all your controls on Canvas. Then you can set Zindex with:

```
this.controlName.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, 10d);
```

Answer (score 3):

Only the `Canvas` panel supports a `ZIndex` property.  Stackpanel doesn't because each item is placed one after the other in the panel so they shouldn't overlap each other.   This can be a little annoying at times when you have animated transforms moving the items about because the previous assumption isn't actually true.

In general though if you need to place items in a visual stack the Stackpanel isn't the right place for it.  Perhaps a `Canvas` or you could use a `Grid` where the oridinal position of a element determines its "zorder" in a cell.

Comment: Even with elements in a Grid, you can use .SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, myValue); and it will work at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

From xaml:

```
<StackPanel Canvas.ZIndex="1">
</StackPanel>
```