# BringToFront / SetZIndex in Universal Windows App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

Apparently [Grid.SetZIndex()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20095018/939213) doesn't exist  . As doesn't [ctrl.SetValue(Grid.ZIndexProperty…)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1802353/939213).

So how do I bring a Child of `Grid` to Front?

Comment: By using the DOM correctly. Or if you must, canvas.zindex

Comment: Ah, fair enough, I just saw the *-store-apps tag, I retracted the close, but you could still use the DOM correctly and accomplish the same.

Comment: @ChrisW. Thanks. But how would I do that (in codebehind, of course)?

Comment: It's all in how your elements get drawn, top to bottom is back to front. Personally I'm a big xaml fan so I'd rarely advocate invoking UI elements from codebehind.

Answer (score 7):

`ZIndex` is only valid inside a `Canvas` control.

```
<Canvas>
    <Grid Canvas.ZIndex="0"/>     
    <Grid Canvas.ZIndex="1"/>     
</Canvas>
```

Otherwise, such as in a `grid`, the placement in the document outline determines the z index. That is to say, the later it is in your XAML page the higher it is in the Z index.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks. But a) According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/573921/939213) it can be used for Grid also. b) So how would I add a Child in a certain location in the Grid's Children?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can find your UIElement in Children and move it on top:

```
// Type of parent element could be any your control
public static void MoveUiOnTop(UIElement element, Grid yourParentElement)  
{
   int index = yourParentElement.Children.IndexOf(element);
   if (index != -1)
     yourParentElement.Children.Move((uint)index, (uint)yourParentElement.Children.Count - 1);
}
```

This example written "on the knee" but I use this small trick from time to time. Or you can try to create extension like this:

```
public static void MoveUiOnTop(this UIElement element, T yourParentElement)
```

but be careful with type of parent element or do not use generic.